# Apache Airflow Celery Executor: Import a local custom python package

Tags: python, celery, airflow, bitnami, python-packaging

I'm using Bitnami's prepackaged Airflow Multi-tier architecture found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bitnami-apache-airflow-multi-tier-now-available-in-azure-marketplace/

Here's what they have to say about how the DAGS are shared across nodes:

> All nodes have a shared volume to synchronize DAG files.
>
> DAG files are stored in a directory of the node. This directory is an
>   external volume mounted in the same location in all nodes (both
>   workers, scheduler, and web server). Since it is a shared volume, the
>   files are automatically synchronized between servers. Add, modify or
>   delete DAG files from this shared volume and the entire Airflow system
>   will be updated.

So, I've set up my dag directory as so:

```
/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
|
├── dag.py
└── package
      ├── __init__.py
      └── module.py
```

This is what the import in my DAG looks like:

```
from package.module import something
```

But I get this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/dag.py] No module named 'package'
```

I've read other threads, and tried those solutions, but nothing seems to work. Does the fact I'm using the celery executor change anything? I'm new here so please, if you need more details, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution.

First, I discovered the airflow plugins manager. It looked like it was mainly for building your own custom operators, hooks, etc, but I figured I could use it for my scenario.

So I checked the airflow.cfg file bitnami provided and saw the parameter:

```
plugins_folder=/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins
```

This directory didn't exist in the machine, so I created it and dropped my  package in there (without making any changes to it).

Then, I restarted the web server node **and** scheduler nodes to pick this change up.

Now I can run the import in my DAG script same as before with no issues:

```
from package.module import something
```

Next steps for me will be synchronizing this plugins folder with the repository that contains our package(s), the same way I synchronized the DAGS folder found here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/infrastructure/apache-airflow/configuration/sync-dags/

I'm not sure the plugins folder is meant to be used this way, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but how we are handling this is having custom airflow images that have all the dependencies needed - in our case a python library that offers domain specific concepts for defining dags.

This way we can just import the library as normal, as it is globaly available.